# C++ std::async() terminate on exception before calling future.get()

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a wrapper that calls std::terminate() when it catch an exception.
I would like this wrapper to take the same arguments as std::async() (it could be a call to a function as well as a call to a method).
Someone know how to make this code to compile ?

Thank you

http://ideone.com/tL7mTv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>

template<class Fn, class... Args>
inline auto runTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    try {
        return std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
    } catch (...) {
        std::terminate();
    }
}

template<class Fn, class... Args>
inline auto runAsyncTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    return std::async(std::launch::async, runTerminateOnException<Fn, Args&&...>, std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct Foo {
    void print() {
        printf("Foo::print()\n");
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::future<void> future = runAsyncTerminateOnException(&Foo::print, &foo);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does compile

Comment: It compiles on your computer ?
There is a compilation error if you follow the link on ideone.com

Comment: Not an answer to this question: but if you want the equivalent behavior of `runTerminateOnException` you can just add the `noexcept` specifier to the function being passed to `std::async`. This will call `std::terminate` when there is an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for c++17.
It works only if we do not use auto for the return type of runTerminateOnException().

```
template<class Fn, class... Args>
inline std::result_of_t<Fn&&(Args&&...)> runTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    try {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch (...) {
        std::terminate();
    }
}

template<class Fn, class... Args>
inline auto runAsyncTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    return std::async(std::launch::async, runTerminateOnException<Fn, Args&&...>, std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: you can remove the try catch block in the first function here by adding a `noexcept` specifier to the function. In fact, using a `noexcept` specifier on a function passed to `std::async` is a viable alternative to even needing to implement a `runTerminateOnException` function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you over complicated it a bit. You can just bind the call and use a simple lambda to do the wrapping.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Fn, class... Args>
inline auto runAsyncTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    auto make_call = std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    return std::async(std::launch::async, [=]() -> decltype(make_call()) {
        try {
            return make_call();
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "Terminate Called!" << std::endl;
            std::terminate();
        }
    });
}

struct Foo {
    void print() {
        printf("Foo::print()\n");
    }
    void print2() {
        printf("Foo::print2()\n");
        throw 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::future<void> future = runAsyncTerminateOnException(&Foo::print, &foo);
    std::future<void> future2 = runAsyncTerminateOnException(&Foo::print2, &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

[See it live, with possible output](http://ideone.com/ti3CgY).

---

I obviously copied the first closure instead of preforming the required step to move it into the second closure (as one would do in c++11). You can of course move it with a specific move capture in c++14.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have an issue when the method to call contains variadic parameters. You can see the problem here : http://ideone.com/psnQgJ. Do you know why it's not working while invoking directly std::async() works ?

Comment: Yes you can see it working here with async() : http://ideone.com/2IiFvp

Comment: @user3782790 I must say it baffles me. I will need to investigate

Comment: I think It was my first issue at the beginning, because I was using a lambda before and it was not working, I oversimplified my code by not using a variadic method in the question.

Comment: @user3782790 The thing is, I think simply trying to `std::bind` a member function template will not allow you to call the closure as well. http://ideone.com/2zUfMD

Comment: @user3782790 The problem is not the variadic template but the forwarding reference in `Foo::print` - You end up with a `void (Foo::*)(int&&)` function, which `std::bind` seems to not like...

Comment: @user3782790 - Holt hit the nail on the end. `std::bind` holds copies of the parameters. When it then passes them on, they are no longer revalues (which is what the call expects). I'm still unsure how `std::async` gets over it.

Comment: Yes Holt is probably right. I am trying to look at the code of std::async(), but I find the code of the C++ Standard Library really hard to read, and the code formating doesn't help ! I don't know why they have those formating conventions

Comment: Thanks. I created another question since this question is different to the original subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124618/wrapper-to-stdsync-not-working

Answer (score 0):

In c++17, the clean way to do this will be to use `std::invoke`.

I have hacked it in here to demonstrate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

namespace std
{
template<class T>
static constexpr bool is_member_pointer_v = std::is_member_pointer<T>::value;
template<class T>
static constexpr bool is_function_v = std::is_function<T>::value;
template<class B, class T>
static constexpr bool is_base_of_v = std::is_base_of<B, T>::value;
namespace detail {
template <class T>
struct is_reference_wrapper : std::false_type {};
template <class U>
struct is_reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<U>> : std::true_type {};
template <class T>
constexpr bool is_reference_wrapper_v = is_reference_wrapper<T>::value;

template <class Base, class T, class Derived, class... Args>
auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmf, Derived&& ref, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept((std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
 -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<T> &&
                     std::is_base_of_v<Base, std::decay_t<Derived>>,
    decltype((std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
{
      return (std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class Base, class T, class RefWrap, class... Args>
auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmf, RefWrap&& ref, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept((ref.get().*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
 -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<T> &&
                     is_reference_wrapper_v<std::decay_t<RefWrap>>,
    decltype((ref.get().*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>

{
      return (ref.get().*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class Base, class T, class Pointer, class... Args>
auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmf, Pointer&& ptr, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
 -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<T> &&
                     !is_reference_wrapper_v<std::decay_t<Pointer>> &&
                     !std::is_base_of_v<Base, std::decay_t<Pointer>>,
    decltype(((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
{
      return ((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class Base, class T, class Derived>
auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmd, Derived&& ref)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd))
 -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_function_v<T> &&
                     std::is_base_of_v<Base, std::decay_t<Derived>>,
    decltype(std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd)>
{
      return std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd;
}

template <class Base, class T, class RefWrap>
auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmd, RefWrap&& ref)
    noexcept(noexcept(ref.get().*pmd))
 -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_function_v<T> &&
                     is_reference_wrapper_v<std::decay_t<RefWrap>>,
    decltype(ref.get().*pmd)>
{
      return ref.get().*pmd;
}

template <class Base, class T, class Pointer>
auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmd, Pointer&& ptr)
    noexcept(noexcept((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmd))
 -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_function_v<T> &&
                     !is_reference_wrapper_v<std::decay_t<Pointer>> &&
                     !std::is_base_of_v<Base, std::decay_t<Pointer>>,
    decltype((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmd)>
{
      return (*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmd;
}

template <class F, class... Args>
auto INVOKE(F&& f, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
 -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_member_pointer_v<std::decay_t<F>>,
    decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
{
      return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
} // namespace detail

template< class F, class... ArgTypes >
auto invoke(F&& f, ArgTypes&&... args)
    // exception specification for QoI
    noexcept(noexcept(detail::INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...)))
 -> decltype(detail::INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...))
{
    return detail::INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
}
}

template<class Fn, class... Args>
inline auto runAsyncTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {

    return std::async(std::launch::async, [=]() -> decltype(auto) {
        try {
            return std::invoke(fn, args...);
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "Terminate Called!" << std::endl;
            std::terminate();
        }
    });
}

struct Foo {
    void print() {
        printf("Foo::print()\n");
    }
    void print2() {
        printf("Foo::print2()\n");
        throw 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::future<void> future = runAsyncTerminateOnException(&Foo::print, &foo);
    std::future<void> future2 = runAsyncTerminateOnException(&Foo::print2, &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

error when invoking templated member function:

The error is this `<source>: In instantiation of 'runAsyncTerminateOnException(Fn&&, Args&& ...)::<lambda()> [with Fn = void (Foo::*)(int&&); Args = {Foo*, int}]':`

implying that Foo::print is demanding an `int&&` of course it is. That's what you wrote:

```
void print(Args&&... args)
```

It's not reasonable for a print function to demand ownership of objects. Declare it as it should be:

```
struct Foo {
    template<class... Args>
    void print(const Args&... args) {
        printf("Foo::print(%d)\n", args...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But unfortunately I have an error when the method to call contains variadic parameters, while invoking directly std::async() works. Here is the same code invoking a variadic method : http://ideone.com/N20Vi4

Comment: Of course I am not using a print function. This is a simplified example. I need to forward parameters in a standard way, this is how the C++ Standard Library handle variadic templates. You can see this pattern in all the C++ Standard Library functions

Comment: And a call to std::async() is handling the print function perfectly, so I would like a wrapper to it to work as well

Comment: You can just add noexcept to the lambda  instead of catching the exception and calling terminate. You can emulate the DECAY_COPY forwarding behaviour of `std::async` by capturing the args as lambda captures and then forwarding those to the `invoke` call (your version makes copies, so doesn't support move-only types). That's easy using a tuple and `std::apply` e.g. `std::async(std::launch::async, [fn=std::forward<Fn>(fn), args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]() mutable noexcept -> decltype(auto) {
              return std::apply(std::move(fn), std::move(args));
            });`

Comment: great point @JonathanWakely  Using noexcept passed to std::async could even be a better solution than implementing a runAsyncTerminateOnException function